# How to enable suexec for VPS using Plesk Panel?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, suexec

I have tested on Plesk 9 and 10(preview version), but I couldn't find a way to enable suexec. The apache has loaded the suexec module, but it was not enabled. The OS is Centos 5.4. Any help will be appreciated.

```
# grep -i suexec /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so

# /usr/sbin/httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

(If the suexec is enabled, we will see something like this under the above modules list
"suexec: enabled; valid wrapper")

```
# locate suexec
/usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_suexec.so
/usr/lib/sw-cp-server/sw-suexec
/usr/local/psa/suexec
/usr/local/psa/suexec/psa-suexec
/usr/sbin/suexec
/usr/sbin/suexec.saved_by_psa
/usr/share/man/man8/suexec.8.gz

# ls -lah /usr/sbin/suexec
-r-s--x--- 1 root apache 23K Sep  1 05:41 /usr/sbin/suexec
```

Answer (score 1):

suexec won't necessarily be listed in the output from `httpd -l` if apache is DSO.

Look in your `error_log` on startup for the following string:

```
[notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```